# How to import Sendgrid in android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints, sendgrid

I would like to use sendgrid to send emails from my google endpoint project, which I am developing in android studio. 
The problem is that I can't find any example of how to import the sendgrid library, I tried this and some other variants:

```
compile 'com.sendgrid:1.0.6'
```

Where 1.0.6 is the latest version? I could find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from cfl actually doesn't work with the newest version of Android Studio. Using the Send-Grid java dependency clashes with various dependencies native to Android Studio. Thankfully I found a forked version made by Dany Santiago. In his example, he uses a user name and password to instantiate the SendGrid object but if you have an API key, you can use that instead to avoid saving your account information on the device. Add this to your dependencies in build.gradle (app) of your Android Studio project:

```
    compile 'com.github.danysantiago:sendgrid-android:1'
```

DO NOT use the sendgrid-java with Android Studio, it will not work. For more information, here is the link https://github.com/danysantiago/sendgrid-android

Also, you don't need to use the example used in the link. If you have an API key for sendgrid, this sample code will work just fine:

```
    //Might need other imports
    import com.sendgrid.SendGrid;
    import com.sendgrid.SendGridException;
    import android.util.Log;


    //Your method you are sending the email from
    public void sendEmail() {
          //Alternate way of instantiating
          //SendGrid sendGrid = new SendGrid(SENDGRID_USERNAME,SENDGRID_PASSWORD);

          //Instantiate the object using your API key String
          SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid('YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY');

          SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();
          email.addTo("example@example.com");
          email.setFrom("other@example.com");
          email.setSubject("Hello World");
          email.setText("My first email with SendGrid Java!");

          try {
               SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
          }
          catch (SendGridException e) {
               Log.e("sendError", "Error sending email");
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
compile 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:2.2.2'
```

At [maven central respository](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sendgrid%7Csendgrid-java%7C2.2.2%7C)